# How do Jehovah's Witnesses pay obeisance to Jesus in their daily lives?

Tags: jehovahs-witnesses, christian-living

I would like to know how Jehovah's Witnesses pay obeisance to Jesus Christ in their daily lives. Do they use expressions such as *“To him who sits on the throne and to the Lamb be blessing and honor and glory and might forever and ever!”* (Rev. 5:14)? How often, when and where do they commonly pay obeisance to Jesus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every prayer is offered through the name of Jesus.

Forgiveness of sins asked for through the merits of Jesus ‘  sacrificial death.

Expression such as “in the name of our reigning King and redeemer Jesus Christ we pray...,”.  “Our Lord and Savior Jesus”.  Are common in daily life.

These can be seen as acts of obeisance.

Comment: All Christians offer their prayers in Jesus' name. Therefore, your answer does not answer the question as to how Jehovah's Witnesses render obeisance on a daily basis. Nothing has been said about how JWs view that word as meaning respect that falls short of worship.That is why I have down-voted it.

Comment: @Anne  1.  I don’t care about the downvote.   2 the question did not aak  for differentiating between obeisance and worship. That was asked in another question. 3 the op felt it answered the question .

Comment: @Kris A couple of observations in your answer. Jesus forgave sins "before" His sacrificial deaf at Luke 5:20-21. "Friend, your sins are forgiven. vs21, And the Scribes and Pharisees began to reason, saying, "Who can forgive sins, but God alone?" Jesus was accused of blasphemy. So what was the blasphemy? You said the "Expression" such as in the name of "Our Lord and Savior Jesus" are common in daily life. 2 Peter 1:11. Why is not the expression at 2 Peter 1:1 not expressed in your daily life? "by the righteousness of our God and Savior, Jesus Christ." Same construction in Greek as at vs11.

Comment: @Mr.Bond what translation are you quoting?

Comment: @Kris The New American Standard Bible. What's interesting is your NWT at 2 Peter 1:11 quotes exactly right, "of our Lord and Savior Jesus Christ." At 2 Peter 1:1 it says in the NWT, "by the righteousness of our God and (the) Savior Jesus Christ. What is the reason for adding the word "the" in the verse when it is not in the Greek? I know why? Because it changes the meaning in order to deny the deity of Jesus Christ. Remember, Christians are suppose to honor the Son exactly the same way we are to honor God the Father.

Comment: You should ask a question about that @Mr.Bond

Comment: This [question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/63695/23657) may be of interest.@Mr.Bond